# 2 outdoor outlets connected to one GFCI controlled by a switch inside

Tags: gfci

I want to add two outlets(front/back yard) I have a working GFCI in front yard--is it feasible to add another outlet for back of house?  Both controlled by one switch--switch off--all dead/switch on-all alive.

Comment: Is the existing GFCI outlet switch-controlled, and where do you want the switch to be located?

Comment: You may also want to consider a wireless switch to control both outlets

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is feasible to do what you want to do. You'd need to run cable/conduit from your existing GFCI load terminals to the new location in the back yard and the new location in the front yard if an additional outlet is desired. If your existing GFCI is switched, then you're good to go. If it's not, then you'd need to find the feed to that GFCI and add a switch.

Depending on your layout and the location of your main panel, it might be easier to just add a new switched circuit for the two new GFCI outlets.

Comment: Have the wire to run to back outlet.

Comment: All repaired... got a electrician over and he untied my knots!

Answer (score 1):

It may get a bit more complicated, but I think the best overall solution is:

- GFCI *inside* - If your existing outside GFCI is still good, you can move it inside.
- Switch inside connected to the LOAD hot terminal of the GFCI.
- Pigtail from LOAD neutral terminal of the GFCI and switched-hot from the switch to wires going to *both* of the outdoor receptacles.
- Replace existing outdoor GFCI receptacle with a regular (not GFCI) weather-resistant receptacle.
- Add new outdoor weather-resistant receptacle in the 2nd location.

This has the advantages that:

- You are switching LOAD instead of LINE, which eliminates power-cycling the GFCI frequently. Some GFCI are designed to handle that just fine, but some require a RESET after power-cycle so it could complicate things to have a switch *before* the GFCI.
- Your GFCI is inside, which protects it 100% from weather and temperature variations, which should help it last longer.

Note that there are both GFCI/switch/receptacle combinations, which *may* be usable here as an alternative to separate GFCI/receptable + switch, as well as some GFCI/receptacle that are designed to be used as switches themselves. But unless specifically designed to be used that way, I would **not** recommend simply installing an ordinary inside GFCI and using "TEST"/"RESET" as a switch.